# Make a loader in Xamarin App (C#)

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Android app.

I realized cache for JSON in .txt file.

But when I goes to category, where is text in JSON shows. Screen is freezing for 2-3 seconds and become black. Than Activity opens and I see all of text of my JSON. I think it's freezing because I download images from url that in JSON.

Can I make something like loader? I will tap a button, see loader and json will be read from file , then I see activity.

I download and cache JSON like this

```
 string url2 = "http://papajohn.pp.ua/?mkapi=getProductsByCat&cat_id=83";
        var json2 = await FetchAsync2(url2);
        var path2 = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filename2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(path2, "cache2.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(filename2, json2);
 public async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        string jsonString;

        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return jsonString;
    }
```

Show JSON on target activity like this

```
   var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "cache4.txt");
        JsonValue readJson;
        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        readJson = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);




     private void ParseAndDisplay1(JsonValue readJson)          
     {
            JsonValue firstitem = readJson[0];

            productname.Text = firstitem["post_title"];
            price.Text = firstitem["price"] + "грн";
            weight.Text = firstitem["weight"] + "г";
            var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl1(firstitem["img_url"]);
            imagen.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
      }
```

Thank's for help.

Comment: try to use any image loader libarary like https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso  ..its more usefull and compartafull  this is nativeport of square picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ProgressDialog` to show a Loaed in First Activity and get the json like below,

```
async Task DownLoadData ()
    {

        string url2 = "http://papajohn.pp.ua/?mkapi=getProductsByCat&cat_id=83";

        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog (this, Resource.Style.progress_bar_style);
        progress.Indeterminate = true;
        progress.SetProgressStyle (ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
        progress.SetCancelable (false);
        progress.SetContentView (Resource.Layout.ProgressLayout);

        var json2 = await FetchAsync2(url2);
    var path2 = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var filename2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(path2, "cache2.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(filename2, json2);
  progress.Dismiss ();  
  }
```

In your second Activity you can load the image Asynchronously using [UrlImageViewHelper Xamarin Component](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/urlimageviewhelper) .

You can add that Xamarin Componentn and then load your Image Asynchronously like below

```
Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (imagen, firstitem["img_url"],Resource.Drawable.ic_dummyprofileimage);
```

where `ic_dummyprofileimage` is a dummy image that you can show till the image gets downloaded asynchronously.

Comment: I try to use UrlImageHelper. Tell me please, how I can cache image using this component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MonoDroid.UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/Redth/MonoDroid.UrlImageViewHelper) to asynchronously download image from internet:

```
var img = this.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.SomeImageView);
img.SetUrlDrawable("http://example.com/image.png");
```

Comment: Error CS1061 'ImageView' does not contain a definition for 'SetUrlDrawable' and no extension method 'SetUrlDrawable' accepting a first argument of type 'ImageView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error CS0117 'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultUrlImage'

Comment: @ЕвгенийСухомлин: Did you add the library I mentioned in my answer? If so you will need to add `using UrlImageViewHelper` to your file.